# If some five vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$, how can I find "real" vectors that works for the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If some five vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$, how can I find "real" vectors that works for the basis?

Please answer me with the assumption that we never have learned any idea of column spaces.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the question? You have to pick a basis: you are guaranteed to be able to find one, but not any choice of three vectors will necessarily be linearly independent.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses without wasting anyone's time explaining what you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Comment: @ElliotG If I have to find three out of five, I should put vectors together and do RREF. and the columns that has leading one is selected. These are the way to find that 3 vectors. I'm curious about other method besides the previous one.

Comment: @이민지: Comments are easily overlooked, so [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3712142/edit) to include your thoughts.